# How to pass a PROPERTY=VALUE from Wix boostraper to setup?

Tags: wix

I'm trying to create a WiX boostrapper that includes a WiX setup that accepts a custom property `ENABLE_TOGGLE`, but when calling the bootstrapper from the command prompt as

`boostrapper.exe /q ENABLE_TOGGLE=1`

it has no effect, while calling the setup

`setup.msi /q ENABLE_TOGGLE=1`

works as expected.

If I specifiy `<MsiProperty Name="ENABLE_TOGGLE" Value="1" />` inside `<MsiPackage >...</MsiPackage>` it works, but I would like this value to be specified at install time.
I've tried to reference it as `[ENABLE_TOGGLE]` but that doesn't seem to work.

I'm using WIX 3.11.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using WixStdBA, you can mark a `Variable` with `Overridable="yes"` to let the user set the variable at the command line.

https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/xsd/wix/variable/

Then `MsiProperty` will work as you expect with `Value=[Variable]`.

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me. Had to import a BalExtension namespace and then `bal:Overridable="yes"`